# Filter on Accounts that currently have one product but not another

Tags: reporting, filters, cross-filter

I need a report that will list out all of our Accounts currently under contract and use one product, but do not have another.  I feel like there might be an easy way to do this and that I am possibly over thinking it.  Let me explain in more detail...

I need to show all Accounts that have a value of "Product Group A" for the Product Family field on the Asset Level, but do not have a value of "Product Group B" for Product Family with any other associated Assets.

So to get more detailed...

Company A has:
Contract 1234 with
Asset 1 - Product Family: Product Group A
Asset 2 - Product Family: Product Group A etc

Contract 2345 with
Asset 3 - Product Family: Product Group B
Asset 4 - Product Family: Product Group B etc

Company B has:
Contract 7654 with
Asset 5 - Product Family: Product Group A
Asset 6 - Product Family: Product Group A etc

Contract 3456 with
Asset 7 - Product Family: Product Group C
Asset 8 - Product Family: Product Group C etc

Company C
Contract 9876 with
Asset 11 - Product Family: Product Group D
Asset 12 - Product Family: Product Group D etc

Contract 2134 with
Asset 13 - Product Family: Product Group C
Asset 14 - Product Family: Product Group C etc

The report would list Company B and not Company A and C

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the structure correctly, you should be able to do this using cross filters and a formula field on the Asset to get the Product Family.
Create a report on Accounts and add two cross filters.
1. Accounts with Contracts where Assets Product Family = "Product Group A"
2. Accounts without Contracts where Assets Product Family = "Product Group B"

[image]

Comment: You know, I saw your post and got excited for a second. But when I tried it the data was not correct.  I think this is because the filter on Assets only looks at Assets and there can be 2, 3 or more Assets on one Account.  So if an Account has both Product Group A and B, the first filter would add it to the report.

Comment: The second filter should remove it from the report? It's saying show me accounts with group a assets but only if they don't have group b assets. Can you add a screen shot?

Comment: Of the filters? Sure.  I ended up using Contracts instead of Assets, but same concept.  When I remove the second filter it changes nothing.  I have 455 records with or without using the second filter.  I also spot checked about 30 or the records and 5 or so had a contract with Product Group A and a second contract with Product Group B    ![Filters][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/68PGW.png

Comment: Can you explain the exact structure. Accounts have Contracts and does a Contract have a lookup to a product?

Comment: Sure, Accounts have Contracts that are imported from an outside source.  The Product Family field is text field, not a lookup from the product. @jjbennett530

Comment: Sorry, found my mistake, I corrected the answer 2nd filter should be accounts without contracts productfamily = to product group b.

Comment: Fabulous! I did not realize that you could set them up in that manner.  Thank you very much!  This did the trick.  The only thing that I don't like about the cross-filter reports is you cannot use fields from the other object you are reporting on.  Is there a trick that you know of there as well.  Thank you again for help.

Comment: Did you try creating a custom report type "accounts with contracts"?

Comment: Bingo, working like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You could write a trigger to calculate the number of unique Asset Products associated with an account on insert and update.

Populate that value on the Account record, then filter out anything > 1

Although maybe I am not understanding your question because in your examples I believe NONE of the companies would be listed as they all have assets with different product families

You said Company B should be listed but it has assets with Product Family Group A and C

Comment: I figured a trigger was going to be my only option.  Just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking something simple. Thanks!

Comment: Right, Company B is the only one that has A and not B.  Company A already has Group A and B and Company C doesn't have A.  Basically we are trying to get a list of our companies that we can upsell/cross-sell to.

Comment: @Liz It could also be written as a Visualforce page, but a trigger would be less work. Not to mention, you'd lose reporting capability, so you'd have to code your own export, if that were a need.